# Error updating CLOB in oracle : ORA-00600: [kcfrbd_2]

Tags: oracle, flush, oracle-enterprise-manager

I get this error when I want to update clob field.If the updated text is short, there is no problem, but when I want to enter a long data, I get an error.  I try to update one column with clob data but
When try to run this code block

```
 DECLARE
        large_txt CLOB;
    BEGIN
        large_txt:='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';
        update test set resim=large_txt where ID=1;
    END;
```

then i get an error

```
 Error report -
    ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kcfrbd_2], [6], [0], [1], [19491072], [19491072], [], [], [], [], [], []
    ORA-06512: at line 5
    00600. 00000 -  "internal error code, arguments: [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s]"
    *Cause:    This is the generic internal error number for Oracle program
               exceptions.  This indicates that a process has encountered an
               exceptional condition.
    *Action:   Report as a bug - the first argument is the internal error number
```

Comment: If your question is "is that a general thing that happens? is that expected?" then the answer is **no**. If your question, instead, is "what might be the specific reasons this is happening **to me**", then obviously you didn't give us enough information. How are you trying to update? Show us exactly what you are doing.

Comment: A code block that has been working flawlessly for 6 years. Due to the sudden shutdown of the database machine, the data as oracle.sql.CLOB@6gc6da was written in the clob field in the table. After making this field null, I started getting such an error.
UpdClass updClass = (UpdClass) GeneralServices.getQueryEmReturn(em, sqlQuery);
updClass.setClobField(clobField);
em.merge(updClass);
em.flush();

Comment: Please check the Oracle Note [2180612.1](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2180612_1.html) (you'll need support contract to log in). The cause seems to be a corrupted temporary tablespace.

Answer (score 0):

`ORA-00600` is a general error code for basically "An internal Oracle error occurred". This is a catch-all error code meaning something outside normal database operations happened. It's probably not a problem with your code. It is something you will have to take up with Oracle Support.

Since you said this started happening after an abnormal database shutdown, I'd say something internal is in an inconsistent state the database cannot understand, but that's just a guess.